# Transfer switch and generator

Tags: generator

I am installing a 100 AMP transfer switch to my 200 AMP meter service on my house.  The transfer switch is a 100 AMP breaker type with a lockable guard on the switch itself.  Is #3 on 2 hots and #5 on ground wire what I need for the 10' long connection cord?

I am purchasing a 17,500E - 17,000 Watt (26,250 surge watts) Electric Start Generac gasoline portable generator.  Will this generator handle 100 AMPS?

Comment: What loads are you putting on the generator?  Also, are you in a jurisdiction that prohibits aluminum wire, where is your main panel mounted, and where are you putting the transfer switch?

Comment: Could you link the transfer switch?

Comment: Your generator will handle about 140 Amps @120V , 70 Amps at 240V and an undetermined mixture of both.  Wait for ThreePhaseEel  and Harper.... they've got something cook'in.

Comment: Many Generac portable generators are strictly receptacle connections, with the largest being a L14-50, which is 50A. To draw more than 12,000 watts requires multiple isolated cord connections.

Comment: Yes, can you link the generator for that matter?

Comment: With a 200 amp service a single switch would need to be 200 amp, unless it is a different design than I have seen. The switch has to be able to handle the ampacity of the service.

Comment: @EdBeal -- not in a standby-subpanel configuration -- that's only true if you're doing whole-house transfer...

Comment: It sounds like it with a single breaker. Since installed at the meter , we don’t really have enough information, but what I read may be issues.